# Set the protocol on a Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a route on the site that is to a webcal resource so we would like the URL to be generated with `webcal://` when using `{{ URL::route('calendar') }}` in the Blade template.

I tried adding a protocol option but this is ignored, so I guess there must be another way?

```
Route::get('/calendar.ics',
    [
        'as' => 'calendar',
        'uses' => 'EntityController@calendar',
        'protocol' => 'webcal'
    ]
);
```

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Are you sure `protocol` is an acceptable array key to pass here?

Comment: @haakym Doesn't seem to have any impact - no error but the protocol is still http. I just guessed this param as it seemed logical, but couldn't find any documentation to support it.

Comment: Try to extend blade for your own method: https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#extending-blade. Take a look at how the current `route()` helper works: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L605 then you can make a `webCalRoute()` method perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The `webcal` URI are not official protocols. The `webcal://` will actually be handed to another app as `http://`.

As suggested, you can either do your own helper for this or write the plain actual URI in your views.

You may also use the `Content-Type: text/calendar` header but I guess it won't be opened in another application.